# svn can't commit *.js or *.css file

Tags: svn, error-handling, commit

When I commit js or css file , The svn plugin in eclipse always appear an error like the following picture.But commiting php/html/xml/json has no problem. Why!!!!!!

commit -m "New file" /Users/llwang/Documents/php_new_workspace/chinafun/zaq.js
    
Adding         /Users/llwang/Documents/php_new_workspace/chinafun/zaq.js
    
**svn: E175002: Commit failed (details follow):
    
svn: E175002: Commit failed (details follow):

svn: E175002: PROPFIND of '/svn/repos/chinafun/trunk/zaq.js': 405 Not Allowed (http://218.245.3.207)
    
svn: E175002: Commit failed (details follow):

svn: E175002: PROPFIND of '/svn/repos/chinafun/trunk/zaq.js': 405 Not Allowed (http://218.245.3.207)**

Comment: You are probably only allowed access on subfolders of this repository and not the whole repository. Try committing a php file in the folder you are adding/committing js/css

Comment: Hello Ozair Kafray, I am getting the same error. What if I want to commit js and css files..?